# How to specify dates as x-axis labels in ggplot? Trying to match dates with geom_vline() R

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
> All_Services_wDUPS
         Var1 Freq
1  2020-03-13    2
2  2020-03-16    5
3  2020-03-18   23
4  2020-03-19    9
5  2020-03-20    5
6  2020-03-21   69
7  2020-03-22   30
8  2020-03-23   33
9  2020-03-24   10
10 2020-03-25    2
11 2020-03-26    2
12 2020-03-27    5
13 2020-03-28    1
14 2020-03-29    9
15 2020-03-30    8
16 2020-03-31   10
17 2020-04-01    1
18 2020-04-03    5
19 2020-04-04    2
20 2020-04-05    1
21 2020-04-06    5
22 2020-04-07    7
23 2020-04-08    8
24 2020-04-09   10
25 2020-04-10  240
26 2020-04-11  102
27 2020-04-12   27
28 2020-04-13    3
29 2020-04-14    1
30 2020-04-15   11
31 2020-04-16   29
32 2020-04-17   10
33 2020-04-18    3
34 2020-04-19    4
35 2020-04-20    5
36 2020-04-21    5
37 2020-04-22    4
38 2020-04-23   10
39 2020-04-24    6
40 2020-04-27    6
41 2020-04-28    8
42 2020-04-29   21
43 2020-04-30    8
44 2020-05-01   10
45 2020-05-02    4
46 2020-05-03    4
47 2020-05-04    4
48 2020-05-05    3
49 2020-05-06    6
50 2020-05-07    4
51 2020-05-08    3
52 2020-05-09    1
53 2020-05-10    1
54 2020-05-11    6
55 2020-05-12    2
56 2020-05-13    1
57 2020-05-14    5
58 2020-05-15    6
59 2020-05-16    2
60 2020-05-17    2
61 2020-05-19    4
62 2020-05-20   32
63 2020-05-21   16
```

And here is my code

```
ggplot(data=All_Services_wDUPS, aes(x=Var1, y=Freq, group=1)) + 
  #Verticle lines
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.Date("2020-03-13")), size=1.2, color = "grey", linetype=2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.Date("2020-05-01")), size=1.2, color = "grey", linetype=2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.Date("2020-05-22")), size=1.2, color = "grey", linetype=2) +
  annotate("text", x=as.Date("2020-03-13"), y=200, label= "First Case of COVID-19", angle=90, vjust=1.2, size=5) + 
  annotate("text", x=as.Date("2020-05-01"), y=200, label= "Texas Reopens at 25%", angle=90, vjust=1.2, size=5) + 
  annotate("text", x=as.Date("2020-05-22"), y=200, label= "Texas Reopens at 50%", angle=90, vjust=1.2, size=5) + 

  #Blue Line TRend
  geom_line(color = "dodgerblue", size = 1.4) + 
  geom_point(color = "dodgerblue", size = 2) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=Freq),hjust=.3, vjust=-1.2, size=5) + 
  ggtitle(label = "All Sales During COVID-19",
          subtitle = "San Antonio") + 
  ylab("Sales in Units") + 
  xlab("") + 
  theme(axis.text.x =
          element_text(size  = 10,
                       angle = 0,
                       hjust = 1,
                       vjust = 1)) +
  #THEME
  theme_minimal() + 
  #X & Y Axis line
  theme(axis.line = element_line(size = 1, colour = "grey42")) + 
  #Larger Font
  theme(text = element_text(size=20))  +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "7 days", date_labels = "%b-%d")
```

This is the plot that is generated

[image]

My problem is that I need dates on my geom_vline() because they are landing on the x axis where there is no label, so its difficult to understand right away.

How can I specify the dates

2020-03-13
2020-05-01
2020-05-22

and still have some ticks on the other x labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, your plot is a bit of a mess with repetitions and elements that cancel others out. Therefore, I have conducted a somewhat larger cleanup of the code:

```r
library(tidyverse)

All_Services_wDUPS <- tibble(
  Var1 = as.Date(c("2020-03-13", "2020-03-16", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-19", "2020-03-20", "2020-03-21", "2020-03-22", "2020-03-23", "2020-03-24", "2020-03-25", "2020-03-26", "2020-03-27", "2020-03-28", "2020-03-29", "2020-03-30", "2020-03-31", "2020-04-01", "2020-04-03", "2020-04-04", "2020-04-05", "2020-04-06", "2020-04-07", "2020-04-08", "2020-04-09", "2020-04-10", "2020-04-11", "2020-04-12", "2020-04-13", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-15", "2020-04-16", "2020-04-17", "2020-04-18", "2020-04-19", "2020-04-20", "2020-04-21", "2020-04-22", "2020-04-23", "2020-04-24", "2020-04-27", "2020-04-28", "2020-04-29", "2020-04-30", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-02", "2020-05-03", "2020-05-04", "2020-05-05", "2020-05-06", "2020-05-07", "2020-05-08", "2020-05-09", "2020-05-10", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-12", "2020-05-13", "2020-05-14", "2020-05-15", "2020-05-16", "2020-05-17", "2020-05-19", "2020-05-20", "2020-05-21")),
  Freq = as.integer(c(2, 5, 23, 9, 5, 69, 30, 33, 10, 2, 2, 5, 1, 9, 8, 10, 1, 5, 2, 1, 5, 7, 8, 10, 240, 102, 27, 3, 1, 11, 29, 10, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 10, 6, 6, 8, 21, 8, 10, 4, 4, 4, 3, 6, 4, 3, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1, 5, 6, 2, 2, 4, 32, 16))
)

vlines <- tibble(
  x = as.Date(c("2020-03-13", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-22")),
  y = 200,
  label = c("First Case of COVID-19", "Texas Reopens at 25%", "Texas Reopens at 50%"),
)

ggplot(All_Services_wDUPS, aes(Var1, Freq)) + 

  #Vertical lines
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = x), vlines, size=1.2, color = "grey", linetype = 2) +
  geom_text(aes(x, y, label = label), vlines, angle = 90, vjust = 1.2, size = 5) +

  #Blue Line Trend
  geom_line(color = "dodgerblue", size = 1.4) + 
  geom_point(color = "dodgerblue", size = 2) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = Freq), hjust = .3, vjust = -1.2, size = 5) + 

  labs(x = "",
       y = "Sales in Units",
       title = "All Sales During COVID-19",
       subtitle = "San Antonio") + 

  theme_minimal() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 1, colour = "grey42"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = 1, colour = "grey42")
        ) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq.Date(as.Date("2020-03-13"), as.Date("2020-05-22"), "week"),
               date_labels = "%b-%d")
```

Your three events are all on the same weekday, so we can just align the weekly axis breaks with the events.

Your `theme_minimal()` had removed the ticks, so to bring them back I specified `axis.ticks` in `theme()`. Importantly, `theme()` must come after `theme_minimal()`, or else your changes will be overwritten.

Now it is a simple matter of creating a custom breaks vector `breaks = seq.Date(as.Date("2020-03-13"), as.Date("2020-05-22"), "week")` in `scale_x_date()`.

I also moved the data for the vertical lines into a separate data frame, reducing the number of layers needed for those from 6 to 2.

Furthermore, I consolidated the plot and axis labels into `labs()` and finally, I removed some clutter and superfluous code.

[image]